# How can I improve my solution to the Hackerrank Maximum Element challenge to avoid timeouts?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to complete the Hackerrank Maximum Element challenge found here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem

My solution produces the correct output, but times out on the final test cases beginning with #17.

Initially, I used a list and loop/recur to get my answer:

```
(defn get-query [] 
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")))

(defn stack-stepper [query stack]
  (condp = (first query)
    1 (conj stack (second query))
    2 (rest stack)
    3 (do (println (apply max stack)) stack)))

(loop [stack '()
       queries-left (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
  (if (> queries-left 0)
    (recur (stack-stepper (get-query) stack) (dec queries-left))))
```

After some research and feedback from other channels, I tried a vector instead of a list, and reduce instead of loop/recur, but the results were the same.

```
(defn get-query [] 
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")))

(defn get-queries []
  (loop [queries      []
         queries-left (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
    (if (= queries-left 0)
      queries
      (recur (conj queries (get-query)) (dec queries-left)))))

(defn stack-stepper [stack query]
  (condp = (first query)
    1 (conj stack (second query))
    2 (pop stack)
    3 (do (println (apply max stack)) stack)))

(reduce stack-stepper [] (get-queries))
```

I am still new to FP and Clojure and I would really like to understand what I am missing. I greatly appreciate your time and help!

Comment: to help make the question more contained, could you include a small sample input to this so i can tell if an answer runs?

Comment: I've voted to move this to the meta site: obviously nonsense. It really belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which we're not allowed to recommend transfer to.

Comment: Sample Input

10,
1 97,
2,
1 20,
2,
1 26,
1 20,
2,
3,
1 91,
3,
Sample Output
26,
91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HackerRank problems are often very demanding from a performance point of view.

The obvious thing to try first is using a transient vector so see if that helps. I tried this:

```
(let [in (clojure.string/split (slurp *in*) #"\s")
         tests (first in)
         input-data (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (rest in))]

  (loop [v (transient [])
         d input-data]
    (when (seq d)
      (condp = (first d)
        1 (recur (conj! v (second d)) (drop 2 d))
        2 (recur (pop! v) (rest d))
        3 (let [pv (persistent! v)] (println (apply max pv)) (recur (transient pv) (rest d)))))))
```

If failed at the same point as your solution. Clearly they're looking for something cleverer than that.

The obvious bottleneck is the calculation of the max value on the current stack, which gets re-calculated each time. We can instead save the previous max value on the stack, and recover it as the current max value when we pop the stack:

```
(defn peek! [tvec] (get tvec (dec (count tvec))))

(let [in (clojure.string/split (slurp *in*) #"\s")
         tests (first in)
         input-data (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (rest in))]

    (loop [v (transient [])
             m 0
             d input-data]
        (when (seq d)
          (condp = (first d)
            1 (let [snd (second d)
                    max-now (max m snd)]
                (recur (conj! v {:val snd :max-prev m}) max-now (drop 2 d)))

            2 (let [popped (peek! v)
                    max (if popped (:max-prev popped) 0)]
                (recur (pop! v) max (rest d)))

            3 (do
                (println m)
                (recur v m (rest d)))))))
```

Which puts me at rank 1 on the leaderboard :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so focused on making sure I used the language properly that I completely overlooked the cost of max over the whole data structure.  I slapped my forehead as soon as you pointed it out, but I did get to learn about transients and slurp because of it. Much appreciated.